# Vertex Buffer Objects/Vertex Array Objects with shaders

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, vbo, vao

I am having trouble getting anything to render to the screen.

```
private void initVBO() {
    vao = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(vao);

    float[] vertices = {
            -0.5f, 0.5f, 0f,
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0f
    };
    FloatBuffer vertBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertices.length);
    vertBuffer.put(vertices);
    vertBuffer.flip();

    this.vboID = GL15.glGenBuffers();
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vboID);
    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    positionAttribute = GL20.glGetAttribLocation(getMaterial().getShader()
            .getProgram(), "position");
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionAttribute);
    GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(positionAttribute, 3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0,
            0);

    Color c = getMaterial().getColor();
    float[] colors = {
        c.red, c.green, c.blue, c.alpha,
        c.red, c.green, c.blue, c.alpha,
        c.red, c.green, c.blue, c.alpha,
    };
    FloatBuffer colorBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(colors.length);
    colorBuffer.put(colors);
    colorBuffer.flip();

    this.vbocID = GL15.glGenBuffers();
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vbocID);
    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    colorAttribute = GL20.glGetAttribLocation(getMaterial().getShader().getProgram
            (), "color");
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(colorAttribute);
    GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(colorAttribute, 4, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    byte[] indices = {
            0, 1, 2,
            2, 3, 0
    };
    ByteBuffer indicesBuffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(indices.length);
    indicesBuffer.put(indices);
    indicesBuffer.flip();

    this.vboiID = GL15.glGenBuffers();
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vboiID);
    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesBuffer,
            GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);

    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionAttribute);
    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(colorAttribute);

    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

public void render() {
    GL20.glUseProgram(getMaterial().getShader().getProgram());

    GL30.glBindVertexArray(this.vao);
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionAttribute);
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(colorAttribute);

    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vboiID);

    GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL11.GL_BYTE, 0);

    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(colorAttribute);
    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionAttribute);
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
    GL20.glUseProgram(0);
}
```

The shaders are compiling correctly, and Im binding the attributes for the position and color correct. Im am just using glOrtho and it is set up correctly because drawing via immediate mode works just fine. I'm not sure if the issue could be from creating the indices or if its a problem within the glVertexAttribPointer. I am just trying to get a rectangle that is colored drawn to the screen.

Update:
Vertex Shader:

```
#version 150

in vec3 position;
in vec4 color;

out vec4 passColor;

void main(void) {
  gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
  passColor = color;
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 150

in vec4 passColor;

out vec4 outColor;

void main(void) {
  outColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

I also updated the init and rendering code above. Also here is the loading code for the shaders:

```
private void load(File vertex, File fragment) {
        this.vertexID = FileUtility.loadShader(vertex, GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        this.fragmentID = FileUtility.loadShader(fragment, GL20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

        programID = GL20.glCreateProgram();
        GL20.glAttachShader(programID, vertexID);
        GL20.glAttachShader(programID, fragmentID);

        GL20.glBindAttribLocation(programID, 0, "position");
        GL20.glBindAttribLocation(programID, 1, "color");

        GL30.glBindFragDataLocation(programID, 0, "outColor");

        GL20.glLinkProgram(programID);
        GL20.glValidateProgram(programID);

        int status = GL20.glGetProgrami(programID, GL20.GL_LINK_STATUS);
        if (status != GL11.GL_TRUE) {
            Log.print(LogLevel.Error, GL20.glGetProgramInfoLog(programID));
        }
    }
```

Comment: How is your projection matrix getting set in the vertex shader? `glOrtho` won't do this unless you're using `#version 110` and `ftransform` or `gl_ProjectionMatrix`, etc.

Comment: I am creating the orthographic matrix via `GL11.glViewport(0, 0, Configuration.getInstance().getWindowWidth(),
                Configuration.getInstance().getWindowHeight());

        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();i
        GL11.glOrtho(-1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1);
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);`

I am not setting the projection matrix within the shaders; I am only setting the color of the vertices.

Comment: How exactly are you planning on using `in`/`out` in un-extended `#version 120` shaders?

Comment: Ive tried using `#version 150` but it doesnt produce any results. I've updated the code

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems here, the main one being that your VBO isn't actually bound.

You create, bind, and then immediately unbind your VAO. So remove the call to `glBindVertexArray(0)` or push it down to the bottom of `initVBO`. Also don't unbind your VBOs until after you unbind your VAO, otherwise your VAO won't be bound to the VBOs.

You didn't post your shaders, but you're using VAOs which means that you have access to at least GLSL 1.30. `glOrtho` with shaders was only briefly supported, becoming deprecacted with GLSL 1.20 and removed in the core profile. I would highly recommend moving away from the fixed-function matrix stack as soon as possible. LWJGL has their own matrix classes, the switch should be really simple.

Barring any other issues in your shader, the first thing should make something appear on screen

Comment: `GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);

        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionAttribute);
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(colorAttribute);

        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);`

So I moved all of these to the bottom in that order, but its still not drawing anything.

Comment: Can you update your question with your shaders? Also disable backface culling if it isn't already, just to check that your face isn't getting culled

Comment: glOrtho has no effect on your shader whatsoever. You are setting your vertices directly to NDC in the vertex shader without touching the fixed-function matrix stack or applying any transformations. You should be seeing a square the color of your material on the bottom-left quadrant of your viewport. If not, disable backface culling and set the color in your fragment shader to a constant color, just for testing purposes

Comment: Culling is disabled, and in the fragment shader I am using a constant color, it's not working.